# Rails: remote_form_for not playing nicely with multiple submit_tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a form with the following:

```
<% form_remote_tag :url => {:action => :wotsit} do %>
  <%= submit_tag "Foo" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Bah" %>
<% end %>
```

I would expect that the submitted parameters would reflect which button had been clicked.  However, no matter which button I click, the submitted parameters include `"commit"=>"Foo"`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

form_remote_tag generates some Javascript that uses Prototype's Form.serialize method to send the values of your form fields to the server.
Form.serialize is always using the first element that has the name "commit", so it's always "Foo".

As a work-around you could add a hidden field & have your submit tags set that field & submit the form:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag "real_commit", "" %>
<%= button_to_function "Foo", "$('real_commit').value='Foo';$('myform').submit();" %>
<%= button_to_function "Bah", "$('real_commit').value='Bah';$('myform').submit();" %>
```

Comment: I thought that would be the reason.  Do you have any ideas for how I can get round this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using one form with two submit tags, you could use either 2x `button_to_remote` or 2x `link_to_remote`:

```
<%= button_to_remote "Foo", :url => { :action => :wotsit } %>
<%= button_to_remote "Bah", :url => { :action => :wotsit } %>
```

I think `button_to_remote` sends "Foo" or "Bah" along. `link_to_remote` definitely does **not**. But then you could use the `:with` option to send anything as a parameter.

Check the [PrototypeHelper documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper.html) for that.

Comment: Unfortunately, if my form has any other fields, they wouldn't get submitted here.

Comment: Yes, that's true. I used this solution for a form that had only one field and used the `:with` option to serialize the fields manually: `:with => "'option1=' + $('my_form_field').value"`. But if you have a lot of fields, that would be a bit intricate.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

### View

```
<% form_remote_tag(:url => {:controller => "test", :action => "test_123"},:html => {:id => "form_test"}) do %>

   <%= hidden_field_tag "submit" %>
   <%= submit_tag "Restore", :id => 'restore',  :value => "", :onclick => "$('download').disabled = true;$('delete').disabled = true;$('submit').value='restore';" %>
   <%= submit_tag "Download", :id => 'download',  :value => "", :onclick => "$('restore').disabled = true;$('delete').disabled = true;$('submit').value='download';" %>
   <%= submit_tag "Delete", :id => 'delete',  :value => "", :onclick => "$('restore').disabled = true;$('download').disabled = true;$('submit').value='delete';" %>

<% end %>
```

### Controller

```
 def test_123
    case params[:submit]
    when "restore"
    when "download"
    when "delete"
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO this is a touch cleaner...

```
<%= hidden_field_tag "real_commit", "" %>               
<%= f.submit "Foo", :OnClick => "$('#real_commit')[0].value='Foo'" %>
<%= f.submit "Bar", :OnClick => "$('#real_commit')[0].value='Bar'" %>
```

Comment: For prototype do: $('real_commit').value='Foo'